# Missing EventQueue entry from Properties table?

Tags: event-queue

Context:
The Properties database table contains rows beginning with EQSTAMP which contain the instance names of the CM and CD servers.

In our master db we only have a reference to the CM server instance.
In our web db we have references to the CM and both CD server instances.
In our core db we only have a reference to the CM server instance.

I am led to believe that remote events are only processed when the instance name does not match the instance name of the server that the event is being executed on, and also the WFFM relies on the eventqueue within the core db in order to transfer form submissions from the website to the CM WFFM database.

So it would appear that I am missing rows from the properties table.
If I remove rows from the properties table locally the appropriate rows are re-added straight away, but on higher environments (staging and production) these rows are not being added.

I am replicating the core dbs between CM and CDs using merge replication.

Questions:
1) is this the expected behaviour considering my local env is a single server and my higher envs are separate servers for CM and CDs?
2) why are the instance names not being added to the properties table in my staging & production environments?

I have noticed that user account changes are reflected across CM and CDs, but WFFM form submissions not being saved to the SQL db on production (although they are on staging).

Comment: Which sitecore version you have? Do you have ScalabilitySettings.config enabled on both CM and CD ? Also what event queue rows you are missing?

Comment: @AhmedOkour we are running 8.1.160302 (update 2) and i do not have the scalabilitysettings.config enabled.  my question is, shouldn't the two CD eventqueues also be appearing in the core DB properties table as these are required to drive WFFM?

Comment: in CM, CD environments you MUST have ScalabilitySettings.config enabled on all servers, otherwise, Sitecore will not process events on the remote servers (CD), 
Im not sure i understand the other section of your question about WFFM

Comment: @AhmedOkour I believe we have implemented some settings manually rather than relying on the scalabilitysettings.config, but i will check.  we have the same codebase on staging and production and staging is functioning correctly.

Comment: @AhmedOkour having checked scalabilitysettings only really sets instancenames which we have left as default. enableeventqueues is set to true via sitecore.config if that is the setting you are referring to.

Comment: @AhmedOkour the other section of my question relating to wffm is to clarify the requirement for the eventqueue CD instance names to appear in the core db properties table. i've been advised by sitecore that WFFM uses the core db eventqueue to transfer form submissions from CD to CM which in turn writes to the WFFM db. if this is the case, then surely the core db properties table must include the CD eventqueue instances in order for this to work?

Comment: Long shot but really important, ALL servers including SQL servers must need to have their time synched, Can you check that?

Comment: @AhmedOkour i am 99% certain they do but i will check.  annoyingly 4 WFFM requests at random intervals have worked on production and staging always works.  neither have the CD eventqueue instancenames within the CM properties table, so either what sitecore have told me is incorrect or its a mystery as to how this works on staging.

Comment: @AhmedOkour have confirmed servers times are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

transpires that contrary to previous advise from sitecore support that you should be replicating the properties table, as otherwise the CM and CD servers have no knowledge of each others event queues.
seems to me that by doing this you are potentially replicating the properties table before the event has actually been processed but i'm led to believe that the instancename ensures this will always work.
i'm still have issues regarding wffm remote events firing, but at least i now know why my properties table was missing those rows